# Is there a specific verb for "going by a vehicle" like in other languages?

Tags: word-request, verbs

Is there no a specific verb in English for "going by a vehicle" like there is in some languages*? In some languages (especially Russian and Ukrainian, Albanian and Hebrew) there's a word that is specific for those who are going by a vehicle -whether they're the drivers or the passengers or even the car by itself.

For example:

- I'm **going** now on the way.
- "Imagine a car **going on** the way and then it stops gently."

Are "hitchhike", "trek", "swan off" commonly used in that sense?

Comment: *other languages* – *which* other languages? I know Russian has a large number of 'movement' related verbs.

Comment: For example: Russian (=ехать), Ukrainian (їхати), I was told also in Hebrew (לנסוע).

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You ask for a word that means "going by a vehicle" yet in your example sentence the subject of the verb **going** is "car". How can a car *go by a vehicle*?  (I hope no one will say "on a car-carrier".)  The phrase *by a vehicle* refers to *a vehicle* as the mode or means of  travel. *They went **by camel** into the desert.*   Do you mean *as* a vehicle? Are you asking for a word to describe what a car does?

Comment: I added a new example and edited the question to make it understood.

Comment: Now are you asking for a verb for what a passenger or driver does? The sentence you added has a person ("I") as the subject of the verb.

Comment: I asked for both since in some languages that I mentioned all of those are in one verb (whether is the passenger or the car they are refereed in one verb in those languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a verb to refer to what a car does (as it moves along the road):

> The car **motored** down the highway.
>
> The car **rolled** along.
>
> The car **sped** off into the sunset.
>
> The car **trundled** down the bumpy dirt road.

We can also use these verbs for what a driver  of a car (and/or passenger in the car) does:

> I | we motored down the highway in my new car.
>
> I  | we rolled along in my car.
>
> I | we sped off into the sunset in my new Mercedes.
>
> I | we trundled down the bumpy dirt road in my old jalopy.

or

> I | we drove down the highway.

If you're looking for a generic verb that can be used of passenger and driver alike:

> We **rode** along in silence.

You can even use the verb **ride** transitively with the road as the direct object:

> We like to ride the highway in silence.
>
> We like to ride the highway with the radio blaring and the windows rolled down.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question and added an example to make it more understood, because according to your answer I saw that you understand my question a little bit differently from what I asked.

Comment: B.t.w. What's about the passive form of "We **are driven** now by a car / bus / train" or "They **were driven** by a car / bus / train"? How does it sounds for the native English speaker ears?

Comment: The vehicle does not do the driving, so that passive form with **by a car** is not idiomatic.  But you can say *They were driven there by car.* meaning that someone (who is not mentioned) took them to that location with a car.  The absence of the article in **by car** indicates a *mode*, here a mode of transport, as in *by train, by wagon, by ship, etc*

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask how you personally would say that you use a car for you travel from home to the university for example: "I'm going by car now so I can't talk now." or "When I went to the university - by bus, I saw something interesting on the way." Would you say it that way?

Comment: For the first: *I'm driving now and can't talk.*   For the second: *On my way to the university I saw something interesting* or *When I was riding the bus to work I saw something interesting.* or *When I was taking the bus to work ...*  or *When I was on the bus I saw something interesting*

Answer (score 1):

*Drive* performs this function in English, it can be used both for persons

> 2 a : to operate a vehicle
>   // learned to drive at the age of seventeen
>   b : to have oneself carried in a vehicle
>   // drove to Canada as a kid

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive))</sub>

and for the vehicles themselves:

> 1. To move along or advance quickly: We could hear the trucks driving along the highway.

<sub>(source: [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/drive))</sub>

For some persons/vehicles, *ride* works as well:

> 1 a: to travel on
>   // ride a bike
>   // ride the bus

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ride))</sub>

but, as Tᴚoɯɐuo notes in the comments, we do not ride a car; we ride *in* a car.

---

Your examples would become:

> - I'm driving/riding on the way now.
> - Imagine a car driving down the way, and then it stops gently.

Words like "hitchhike", "trek", "swan off" have very specific meanings and are never used in a general sense.

Comment: "Drive" performs it in English even if I'm not the driver, like in other languages? As for your last paragraph, in other language the specific word is used for both: for the car and for the people who are inside.

Comment: Yes, it's less common but I found another dictionary entry to support this.

Comment: Ok, thank you. What's about the other words that I brought in my question? (I took them from google translate as translated words for my request.)

Comment: Those have very specific meanings, e.g. [hitchhiking](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hitchhike) when you're trying to get a free ride.

Comment: We *ride in a car*.  There, **ride** is intransitive.

Comment: I was always taught that you *drive* a car and *ride* a bike, but I'm happily corrected by a native speaker.

Comment: *ride a bike* is correct.  There, **ride** is transitive.  But as you say, we do not "ride a car" (unless it is a train car or a trolley car).  Rather, we "ride *in* a car" (e.g. in a sedan).